# How to use fillna() with values from another column and delete that particular column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have this Dataframe after some operation

```
     number vehicle  series vehicle1  
      123    xyz1     0.0      abc    
      123    xyz2     1.0      NaN   
      123    xyz3     2.0     xyz4    
      123    xyz4     NaN      NaN 
      456    xyz5     3.0     xyz6    
      456    xyz6     NaN      NaN
```

I want the following data frame

```
     number vehicle  series vehicle1  
      123    xyz1     0.0      abc    
      123    xyz2     1.0      NaN   
      123    xyz3     2.0      NaN   
      123    xyz4     2.0      NaN    
      456    xyz5     3.0      NaN    
      456    xyz6     3.0      NaN
```

What I did,

```
     df.loc[~df['vehicle1'].isin(df['vehicle'].unique())]
```

Separate two frames and used concat() function but series is not machining.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit how the values of `series` and `vehicle1` got mapped ?

Comment: It was given as an input.

Comment: I mean what are the criteria that contribute to the changes you want.  Why the second last entry of `series` is changed from 3.0 to 2.0, etc.

Comment: Say, vehicle number is present in two columns, then I want to take it in the 1st column with the series number and delete it from 2nd column if not then put it as it is just like 'abc' in the 2nd column.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I have corrected that part for second last entry.

Comment: And why the `NaN` values in `serieis` got changed ?

Comment: Kindly see the previous comment, xyz4 has value 2,in this way I want to fill. Thanks.

Comment: You mean for `Series` you got a different (reverse) logic.  Filling `NaN` values from the corresponding value of `value2` ?   I think you have missed out all this requirement details in your question.

Comment: No! I don't want xyz4 in vehicle1 column that is why it is NaN as it is present in vehicle column. I hope, it is clear now.

Comment: `xyz4     NaN`   becomes `xyz4     2.0`  (where is the 2.0 come from?)  and  `xyz6     NaN` becomes `xyz6     3.0 `  where is the 3.0 come from ?

Comment: It is still not clear how the values from `Series` column got changed ?

Comment: xyz4 is mapped with xyz3, I am taking the series same value as xyz3. Similarly xyz6 is mapped with xyz5 (Series value of xyz5 is 3.0).

Comment: See my solution below.  Note that when you process the `Series` column, we have to refer to the old values of `vehicle1` before update, so we need to create a helper column to keep its old values before update.

Comment: See if any further clarification from my answer.  It's not that straightforward and hence the codes seems long.  That's why I need to clarify with you the detailed requirement before I can come up with a solution.

Comment: @SeaBean It is fine. I am not using this same code but certainly it is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: That's fine if you have solved the problem.  Glad that my code is helpful.  Feel free to let me know whether my solution need any amendment such that you can accept the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 masks and update values

```
mask = df['vehicle1'].isin(df['vehicle'])
mask1 = df['vehicle'].isin(df['vehicle1'])

df.loc[mask1, 'series'] = df.loc[mask, 'series'].values
df.loc[mask, 'vehicle1'] = np.NaN
```

```
>>> df
   number vehicle  series vehicle1
0     123    xyz1     0.0      abc
1     123    xyz2     1.0      NaN
2     123    xyz3     2.0      NaN
3     123    xyz4     2.0      NaN
4     456    xyz5     3.0      NaN
5     456    xyz6     3.0      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I did it this part but series value of xyz4 will be 2.0 and xyz6 will be 3.0. xyz4 is mapped with xyz3, I am taking the series same value as xyz3. Similarly xyz6 is mapped with xyz5 (Series value of xyz5 is 3.0) This is where value is coming.

Answer (score 1):

We can create 2 dict for mapping the values of `vehicle` to `series` and `vehicle1` to `series`.  Then check whether `vehicle1` is in `vehicle` by using `.isin()`.

We used [`.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) so that if the condition is true, the values will be replaced by the contents of the 2nd parameter.

```
df['vehicle1_X'] = df['vehicle1']    # copy column before change for later use

df['vehicle1'] = df['vehicle1'].mask(df['vehicle1'].isin(df['vehicle']), df['vehicle1'].map(dict(zip(df['vehicle'], df['series']))))

df['series'] = df['series'].mask(df['series'].isna() & df['vehicle'].isin(df['vehicle1_X']), df['vehicle'].map(dict(zip(df['vehicle1_X'], df['series']))))

df = df.drop('vehicle1_X', axis=1)   # remove the helper column
```

Result:

```
print(df)


    number vehicle  series vehicle1
0     123    xyz1     0.0      abc
1     123    xyz2     1.0      NaN
2     123    xyz3     2.0      NaN
3     123    xyz4     2.0      NaN
4     456    xyz5     3.0      NaN
5     456    xyz6     3.0      NaN
```